# cURL can connect to localhost but browser cannot

Tags: windows-10, curl, netstat, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My system is Win10 with WSL2, I ran a `gogs` docker container (from ubuntu in WSL):

```sh
    83b2a8833235   gogs/gogs                    "/app/gogs/docker/st…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:10022->22/tcp, :::10022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10080->3000/tcp, :::10080->3000/tcp       gogs
```

I found that I can cURL it, but cannot use browser to visit it:

```
    >curl -vvv http://localhost:10080
    * Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:10080/
    *   Trying ::1...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 10080 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:10080
    > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    < Location: /install
    < Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Path=/; Max-Age=2147483647
    < Set-Cookie: i_like_gogs=64602dcbf733a9e0; Path=/; HttpOnly
    < Set-Cookie: _csrf=CEoPJD9KItxBKOThbeQExNAjnDo6MTYyNzQ4MDI3Njg1MDY2NTEwMA; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Expires=Thu, 29 Jul 2021 13:51:16 GMT; HttpOnly
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < X-Frame-Options: DENY
    < Date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 13:51:16 GMT
    < Content-Length: 31
    <
    <a href="/install">Found</a>.
    
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Using `netstat -a -o` I can see the address in Active Connections:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:10080          xxxxxxx:0          LISTENING       13152
```

But I cannot visit using browser:
[image: Cannot Visit Using Browser]

Anyone has any hints?

Comment: Do you have a proxy in your browser ? Or anti-virus which blocks ? The proxy may block of you use the "unsafe port" 10080...

Comment: @vidarlo it is WSL2, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Dom did not see any strange things on the proxy (only the "Automatically detect settings" is set to ON)

Comment: The error text is misleading: Chrome isn't having trouble connecting, **Chrome isn't _trying_ to connect** -- see https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome . Firefox gives a much better error: "This address is restricted / This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection." Your best solution is to choose a different port.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for the knowledge, it works when I change the port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Browsers restrict 10080 for security reasons on localhost

## Solution

- Change the Port.

### References

[Google Chrome blocks port 10080 to stop Nat slip streaming attacks](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/google-chrome-blocks-port-10080-to-stop-nat-slipstreaming-attacks/)
[Chrome Platform](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6510270304223232)

#### Additonal Informations:

Currently, Google Chrome is blocking also FTP, HTTP, and HTTPS access on ports 69, 137, 161, 554, 1719, 1720, 1723, 5060, 5061, and 6566.

Comment: As Also, the most modern browsers do the same.

Comment: Thanks @djdomi for the knowledge!